# Hide certain fields from a spring request body in swagger

Tags: spring, swagger

The example api below lets users create an object. The user should be able to specify the `name` field of the `Thing` object, while the `id` field should be automatically generated.

Given the setup below, swagger will display *both* the name and the id field for the request as something the user can enter, as well as displaying both fields as optional. In reality, for the request, `name` should be required while `id` should never be entered by the user.

(Note: the object that is *returned* when creation is successful, should include the generated id field)

I suppose one option would be to create a copy of the Thing object that is identical, except for the lack of the `id` field ("ThingCreationRequestObject").

Is this an acceptable solution? It seems there should be a way that doesn't require the maintenance of two objects that essentially represent the same thing.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/thing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
Thing createThing(@RequestBody Thing thing) {
    // add thing to database, including a generated id
    // return thing object, now including the generated id
}

public class Thing {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}

// Swagger
Thing {
    id (string, optional),
    name (string, optional)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate the `id` field with `@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)` , in this case it will be hidden from swagger, but still if the user entered the `id` then it will parsed and assigned to the `id` field so you need also annotate the `setter` method only of the id with `@JsonIgnore`

```
public class Thing {

    @ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task. The solution is based on using the @JsonView annotation.
Added the following class View

```
public class View {
    public interface OnCreate extends Default {}
    public interface OnUpdate extends Default {}
}
```

Then add the @JsonView annotation with markers to the controller and to the model field

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/thing", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@JsonView(View.OnCreate.class)
Thing createThing(@RequestBody Thing thing) {
    // add thing to database, including a generated id
    // return thing object, now including the generated id
}

public class Thing {
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonView(View.OnUpdate.class)
    private String id;
    
    private String name;
}
```